# Input representation in FFT for a given list of amplitudes and sampling rate

Tags: signal-processing, fft, dft

How to represent a use a sound wave (Sine wave, 1000Hz, 3sec, -3dBFS, 44.1kHz) in FFT program? The input for the program is list of amplitues and sampling rate.

I mean how to transform a sound file(Eg: XYZ.wav file) as input to FFT where one of the input argument needs to take a .dat file consisting of amplitudes and other input arguments needs to take sampling rate and if any necessary.

Comment: The 44.1kHz refers to your sample rate, so the sample rate is 1/44100. Your wave file should also specify the sample rate as well. It depends on what program you use to read the wav file, but they should all give you the sample rate and the data.  Finally, please carefully rewrite your question to make it clear what you are doing: what programming language are you using; a wav file (a data object) is not a sound wave (a physical object); you probably don't need a ".dat" *file* but the data from the wav file; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you execute a fft call you supply a one dimensional array which represents a curve in the time domain, often this is your audio curve however fft will transform any time series curve ... when you start from an audio file,  say a wav file, you must transform the binary data into this floating point 1D array ... if its wav then the file will begin with a 44 byte header which details essential attributes like sample rate, bit depth and endianness ... the rest of the wav file is the payload ... depending on bit depth you will then need to parse a set of bytes then transform the data from typically 16 bit which will consume two bytes into an integer by doing some bit shifting  ... to do that you need to be aware of notion of endianness (big or little endian) as well as handling interleaving of a multi-channel signal like stereo ... once you have the generated the floating point array representation just feed it into your fft call ... for starters ignore using a wav file and simply synthesize your own sin curve and feed this into a fft call just to confirm the known frequency in will result in that frequency represented in its frequency domain coming out of the fft call

The response back from a fft call (or DFT) will be a 1D array of complex numbers ... there is a simple formula to calculate the magnitude and phase of each frequency in this fft result set ... be aware of what a Nyquist Limit is and how to fold the freq domain array on top of itself to double the magnitude while only using half of the elements of this freq domain array ... element 0 of this freq domain array is your DC offset and each subsequent element is called a frequency bin which is separated from each other by a constant frequency increment also calculated by a simple formula ... pipe back if interested in what these formulas are

Now you can appreciate people who spend their entire careers pushing the frontiers of working the algos behind the curtain on these api calls ... slop chop slamming together 30 lines of api calls to perform all of above is probably available however its far more noble to write the code to perform all of above yourself by hand as I know it will open up new horizons to enable you to conquer more subtle questions

A super interesting aspect of transforming a curve in time domain into its frequency domain counterpart by making a fft call is that you have retained all of the information of your source signal ... to prove this point I highly suggest you take the next step and perform the symmetrical operation by transforming the output of your fft call back into the time domain

> audio curve in time domain --> fft --> freq domain representation --> inverse fft --> back to original audio curve in time domain

this cycle of transformation is powerful as its a nice way to allow you to confirm your audio curve to freq domain is working